# How to compile libdp.dll as 64 bit architecture on windows

Tags: windows, compilation, 64-bit, mingw, libpd

I'm trying to build libpd on windows https://github.com/libpd/libpd

The problem I'm having is that when I build with the given "mingw_build.bat" - the libpd.dll that is built is 32 bit architecture.

How can I build using MingW so my resulting DLL is 64 bit architecture?

Answer (score 0):

afaict there is no ready-made solution for this.

here are some generic hints (haven't tried them):

- you would need to install `mingw64` (the *mingw_build.bat* seems to assume that you are using `mingw32`)
- fix the paths in `mingw_build.bat`
- additionally set the C-compiler to one that produces 64bit binaries:

  ```
   CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
  ```